# Facebook Graph API Places; define category

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to define a category when doing a lookup for places through the facebook graph API?

NB. http://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/search?type=place&center=lat,lon&distance=1500&access_token=token

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. But you can add a query parameter named `q` where you can specify further details.

How Facebook uses this parameter in its search algorithm is unfortunately unspecified. To be sure, you'll need to filter in your application.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer will be to filter this 'client-side' instead of 'server-side' (which in this case is the API)?

Comment: That wasn't the original question... And please use the comments instead of adding answers